# Вопрос о запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?
Дружба дружбой, а есть и другие способы понравиться, и они тоже довольно действенные.

Comment: Вопрос для младших школьников, вроде договаривались не отвечать?

Answer (score 7):

Перед первой И не нужна, это усилительная частица. Перед второй - нужна, так как это сочинительный союз, соединяющий части сложного предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужна, потому что "и" соединяет части сложного предложения